# Login with Google, Facebook, etc, with own API

Tags: php, api, authentication, facebook-login, google-signin

I have a problem to find the right way of implementing a login service. 
First my environment:

1. An Android or IOS APP
2. My own web-api in PHP

Now the users have to login to get specific data from the api. So I have to check if the user is logged in with the API.
First i thought I could do this with JWT (JSON Web Token). But users with existing Google or Facebook account should also login to my side.
Is there a way to implement the login in PHP (the API site)? The most examples to login with Google or Facebook are simple Websites and not an APP with API.

How could I implement this login system?
Some time ago I thougt I could use GIT (Google Identity Toolkit). But now they switch to firebase and the website only contains examples for Webapps and Android/IOS.
Is there a common technique to do a login system like mine?
Do I have to implement OAuth2?

Oh. Besides the Google/Facebook login, there sould be a way to login with email and password.

I'm a little bit confused. It can not be, that I'm the only one with this problem. Or do I am a blockhead?

Comment: I think this will help you http://hybridauth.github.io/hybridauth/

Comment: here latest example of [google login](http://myphpinformation.blogspot.in/2016/12/login-with-google-with-php-example.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is posible and it is well documented on the API's page.

For **Facebook** login, you can check this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login).
For the **Google**'s case, you should check this [link](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app#callinganapi)

*Side note*: I know that I should quote the relevant parts of the link, but there are too much steps to follow, specially on the Google's case, so I haven't done it to avoid a huge block of quotes.

**Solution**: 
Implement the Login in the Android- or IOS-App and get there the access token. Now send this token to the API. There you can check it and to everything you want with the Facebook-/Google-API.

Comment: Thank you.
But if I implement the Facebook login, I'm redirected to the facebook website to authentificate my login. 
How is this on android? Is this link be opened by the facebook app, or do I have to follow the link in my webbrowser and do everythink there?

Comment: Do you want something like thishttps://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android

Comment: Yes, somethink like this would be great. But how could I check in the API if the users is logged in, when I implement the login button in the android app?

Comment: You really need to read the link that I post in my previus comment, since you have the answer to your question there.  Te SDK prrovides the methods `AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()` and `Profile.getCurrentProfile()` to check that.